# using ng-repeat on a json object

Tags: angularjs

I'm just starting off with angularJS and am having trouble with my ng-repeat. So, in my `component.js` file, I have `$scope` declared as `vm` and have declared an array of objects:

```
vm.locOptionFields =
        {
            "locOptionFieldKey": 1,
            "fieldID": "Allow additional material to be added to Orders that have been processed but not shipped",
            "stringNum": 11,
            "taskKey": 12,
            "type": "checkbox",
            "seqNum": 13,
            "comboOptionRefKey": 1
        },
        {
            "locOptionFieldKey": 2,
            "fieldID": "Require requested delivery date",
            "stringNum": 12,
            "taskKey": 13,
            "type": "number",
            "seqNum": 14,
            "comboOptionRefKey": 1
        },
        {
            "locOptionFieldKey": 3,
            "fieldID": "Default Requested Delivery Date into Promise Date",
            "stringNum": 13,
            "taskKey": 14,
            "type": "combobox",
            "seqNum": 15,
            "comboOptionRefKey": 2
        };
```

I want to then reference that information in my .html file and, using `ng-repeat` print out the `taskKey` for each object. I tried doing this:

```
<li ng-repeat="loc in vm.locOptionFields">
    {{loc.type}}
</li>
```

but all that's doing is giving me blank list items, one for each element of the object. However when I just print out `{{loc}}`, it prints out each of the items, only for the first object. Is it only recognizing the first object for some reason?

Comment: You forgot the `[` and `]` enclosing your array of objects. With this syntax and forgiveness of JS, this doesn't throw an error, but only your first object will be in your variable, the others are just ignored. Small note: this is javascript object, not JSON.

Comment: @Kaddath ahh okay, makes sense. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using an array. You are missing the `[]` around the declaration of objects.

Adding those in and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/g6dn0j7o/